# Prinf statement in C language output error, need help in printing \ and doesn't take it as \n for a hangman silhouette

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to make this Hangman silhouette:

[image: Hangman silhouette]

But I am finding an issue with the `printf` statement as it is taking the `\` as a command for `\n` instead of the right leg and for future code the right hand.

Anything I can do to fix it?

Code below is the hang man with no arms.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|  / \ \n|\n=========");
}
```

Comment: Think about `"\ "` and what it might do in your string. What does your books or tutorials say about how to *escape* the single backslash to print a backslash?

Comment: @Ocelotter, With `#include <iostream>`, are you using a C compiler for this code?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Does it really matter since C++ rules for escaping backslash is effectively the same?

Comment: @BrianMcFarland C++ have raw string literals where such escapes are not needed. On the other hand the newlines won't work as is then.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. There is no `<iostream>` in C. On the other hand, in C++ `printf` is not brought in by including `<iostream>`, you need `<cstdio>` fort that (and it's properly called `std::printf`), We don't use `printf` in C++ much anyway. Please decide which language you are trying to learn.

Comment: Missed `<cstdio>` vs `<iostream>`.  Main question is about string escape syntax though, which excluding raw strings (which this isn't using), the syntax issue is the same.  Speak for yourself RE "We don't use `printf` in C++ much".  Quick search of my current Android source tree (as in, the OS, native frameworks, userspace, tools, etc), shows `printf` outnumbers `cout` usage almost 2:1. That's not including `fprintf`, `sprintf` or `ALOGx` macros, which are also `printf` format.

Comment: the iostream is just a default thing in my visual studios because I installed c++ package first, but the code works for c language though.

Comment: Rather than putting "answered" in the title, you should [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

you can use double \\ so it won't take it as an escape character.
so your code will be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes must be doubled in strings to appear as themselves. Also break the string into multiple pieces, one row per line for readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("\n"
           "  +---+\n"
           "  |   |\n"
           "  |   O\n"
           "  |  /|\\\n"
           "  |  / \\\n"
           "  |\n"
           "=========\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Or seen from the other side as in the picture:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("\n"
           "  +---+\n"
           "  |   |\n"
           "  O   |\n"
           " /|\\  |\n"
           " / \\  |\n"
           "      |\n"
           "=========\n");
    return 0;
}
```